# Accessing different elements in an array returned from a WebMethod

Tags: c#, ajax, json, webmethod

I have a WebMethod which returns a string of array:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string[] GetDataFromServer()
{
    return new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };
}
```

I am calling the WebMethod using the following code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "MyPage.aspx/GetDataFromServer",
    data: "{}",
    success: function (msg) {
        alert(msg.d);
    },
    error: function (x, e) {
        alert("The call to the server side failed. " + x.responseText);
    }
});
```

Since the WebMethod is returning an array of string, when calling `alert(msg.d);`, I am getting all the elements of the array seperated by a `,`. I understand that I can split the `msg.d` by the `,` seperator but I don't think that it is good practice. How can I access the different elements in the resulting array by index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to use `msg.d[0]`, for example to get the first item in the array.